# Setting the mask of a view controller's view property and that view's tableview subview results in two masks that look different

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, mask

I'm using the following code to set a view controller's view's mask:

```
view.mask = UIView(frame: view.frame)
view.mask?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.25)
view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

and then I'm also using the following code to set the above view's scrollView subview's mask:

```
scrollView.mask = UIView(frame: scrollView.frame)
scrollView.mask?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.25)
scrollView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

The masks show up completely different though (the view's mask is much much darker than the scrollView's. Anyone have any idea why this might happen?

Comment: Add the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

In above question your are using `view` that is added by default but if you want to apply your mask in your scrollView that is outleted then you need to add, `addsubview` method like i have implemented below, Try this

```
scrollview.mask = UIView(frame: scrollview.frame)
scrollview.mask?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.25)
scrollview.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
scrollview.addSubview(scrollview.mask!)
```

Comment: I've already done this. All subviews are added correctly. The question is why the masks show up differently.

Comment: if you will not add `addSubview` for default view then it will add mask on top of `UIWindow` and `UIWindow` default colour is black that's why it's showing dark in that case

Comment: That's not true. When I add the mask for scrollView, it shows up fine. When I add the mask to view it shows up darker. So it has nothing to do with adding subviews or not.

Comment: i have tried same thing if you will not add `addSubView` for main view that is created by system default then it will add mask on to the `UIWindow` but if you will add `view.addSubview(view.mask!)` then it will add mask on top of the main view

Comment: Again, it has nothing to do with the addSubview. The scrollView was a subview of the view in both my test cases.

Comment: did you try my solution? first, try it and if it is not working then you can downvote my answer.

Comment: no, i did not try it. I solved it by changing alpha components.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of observations:

1. You do not want to use the `frame` of the view when setting the `frame` of the mask. Use the [`bounds`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622580-bounds) instead.

   A view's mask should be placed within the view’s coordinate system, which `bounds` is, but `frame` is not. The `frame` is defined within the superview’s coordinate system. So you want:

   ```
   override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
       super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

       view.mask = UIView(frame: view.bounds)
       view.mask?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.25)
   }
   ```

   If your view happens to have its origin at `0, 0`, you might not notice the difference between using `frame` and `bounds`, but the former is incorrect and will lead to problems if a view ever isn’t at `0, 0`.
2. Note, I’m setting that in [`viewDidLayoutSubviews`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621398-viewdidlayoutsubviews) so that if something triggers the view’s size to change, the mask is updated accordingly. You may well be doing this, too, but I mention it just to be clear. If you happened to be doing this sort of stuff in a `UIView` subclass (rather than `UIViewController` subclass), you’d do this in [`layoutSubviews`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews) instead.
3. A scroll view’s `mask` scrolls with the scroll view. So if that mask’s height is the height of the scroll view’s `bounds`, as soon as you scroll, the scroll view’s mask scrolls up, and anything beyond the mask’s `frame` won’t be visible at all.

   So you can set the `size` of the mask’s `frame` to be the `contentSize` of scroll view. Or I’d personally add the mask to superview of the scroll view, not to the scroll view itself) (so the mask won’t scroll). But setting a mask for a scroll view to be the size of the scroll views’s `bounds`/`frame` rather than its `contentSize` will not achieve what you desire.
4. It’s not clear from your question, but are these two sibling/adjacent views or is one a subview of another? If the latter, that can be problematic. If you set a mask (with alpha below 1) to a view, that mask is applied to all of its subviews, too. So, if a view with a 0.25 alpha mask has a subview which has its own 0.25 alpha mask, effectively that subview will be rendered with 0.0625 alpha.

But here is a text view and scroll view with a label, both at 25% alpha, without one being a subview of another, and it works fine:

[image]

That having been said, I’d advise adding the alpha to a common superview, solving both the scrolling and masks-on-masks issues.